# Take the best row from two table on a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables with almost the same data from two companies with different prices.

I want to select the row from any one of the table which has low price.

How do I compare rows and take the best value from the two table

I have written the query as this but there is ambiguity in the price part.

```
select min(Price), Brand, a.Color 
from [table1] a, table2 b 
where a.BrandName = b.BrandName and a.Shape like b.Shape 
      and (a.color = b.color or a.Color is null)
```

I am getting ambiguity error in price. How do i Solve it.

Comment: Help us help you - please share you table structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for this sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `UNION` if you wanna use `MIN` :

```
SELECT min(price),brand,max(color)
FROM (select price,brand,color FROM table1
      UNION
      select price,brand,'' FROM table2)
GROUP BY brand
```

Or alternatively you can use `CASE EXPRESSION` with a join:

```
select CASE WHEN a.price > b.price then b.price else a.price end as min_price
       ,a.Brand
       ,a.Color
from table1 a
INNER JOIN  table2 b
ON a.BrandName=b.BrandName
WHERE and a.Shape like b.Shape and (a.color=b.color or  a.Color is null)
```

Comment: This is giving me the other way round. its giving me the maximum value. I dont have any PK or FK because its just the data collected randomly.

Comment: I just changed the condition here as  a.price < b.price and got the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
 select 
    case when min(a.price)<min(b.price) then min(a.price) else min(b.price) end as     min_price, 
    Brand,a.Color from [table1] a, table2 b where a.BrandName=b.BrandName and a.Shape = b.Shape and a.color=b.color
group by Brand,a.color
    UNION 
    select 
    case when min(a.price)<min(b.price) then min(a.price) else min(b.price) end as     min_price, 
    Brand,a.Color from [table1] a, table2 b where a.BrandName=b.BrandName and a.Shape = b.Shape and  a.Color is null
group by Brand,a.color
```

Comment: This is not woking I think you have to add group by also and the minimum price should be from any one of the table.

Comment: ya you have to add group by, i didn't add group by because i just drafted the logic based on the code you had shared. i will edit re post my answer